# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data error on multi rating wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

> i got this error on multi rating plugin when click to submit my rating
>   SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>   Showing this

```
m.parseJSON(b="<script src="https://aja...ost multiple times."}]}")jquery.js (line 4)
r(r="<script src="https://aja...ost multiple times."}]}")fronten...r=4.5.3 (line 1)
frontend-min.js?ver=4.5.3(t="<script src="https://aja...ost multiple times."}]}")fronten...r=4.5.3 (line 1)
m.Callbacks/j(l=[Object { url="http://solutionsofts.com...wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", type="POST", isLocal=false, more...}, ["<script src="https://aja...ost multiple times."}]}", "success", Object { readyState=4, responseText="<script src="https://aja...ost multiple times."}]}", status=200, more...}]])jquery.js (line 2)
m.Callbacks/k.fireWith(a=Object { url="http://solutionsofts.com...wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", type="POST", isLocal=false, more...}, c=[Object { url="http://solutionsofts.com...wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", type="POST", isLocal=false, more...}, ["<script src="https://aja...ost multiple times."}]}", "success", Object { readyState=4, responseText="<script src="https://aja...ost multiple times."}]}", status=200, more...}]])jquery.js (line 2)
x(a=200, b="OK", c=Object { text="<script src="https://aja...ost multiple times."}]}"}, d="Server: nginx/1.10.1\r\nDa...ontent-Encoding: gzip\r\n")jquery.js (line 4)
.send/b(c=readystatechange , e=undefined)jquery.js (line 4)

...tion(b){if(a.JSON&&a.JSON.parse)return a.JSON.parse(b+"");var c,d=null,e=m.trim(...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that you are trying to parse a string that is not in JSON format. The parameter of the *parseJSON()* method has to be a properly formatted JSON string. The code you provided shows that you are indeed trying to parse something which is not a JSON string (*b="<script ...*)

Answer (score 0):

Try to display the string that is returned, copy it to a JSON check service (e.g. http://jsonlint.com), and look at the results.

If it says that the string you checked is a valid JSON string, then the problem is somewhere else, but this error shows up here. You have to debug for the error.

If it says that the string you checked is NOT a valid JSON string, then this is your (first) problem.